# How do I calculate the derivative of a square root?

Tags: derivatives

I have the following funtion:
f(x) = 3-½√(6-4x)

Now, I would have no idea how to calculate the derivative and the answer booklet doesn't make it any more obvious because according to the answers it should be:

f'(x) = 0-½ . -4 . 1/2√(6-4x) = 1/(√6-4x)

can anyone explain to me what is happening and how they get to this answer?

Comment: is it $$f(x)=3-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{6-4x}$$?

Comment: Yes it most definitely is

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: Oh, thanks Chase! :)

Comment: Hint: Use the chain-rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that by chain rule

$$f(x)=c+\sqrt{g(x)}\implies f’(x)=\frac{g’(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}$$

Comment: So, if this is a standard formula, I can use this on any kind of square root?

Comment: Yes the derivative of the constant is zero and the derivative of $\sqrt{g(x)}$ is given by the above expression. Can you derive it by chain rule $f(g(x))=f’(g(x))\cdot g’(x)$?

Comment: It is not a standard formula.  The standard formula for the chain rule is $f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'x$. This answer shows how it applies to your particular problem, so do not memorize it!  It leaves out that $f(x)= c+g(x)^{1/2} \to f'(x) =0 + \frac 12g(x)^{-1/2}\cdot g'(x) $ (by the power rule & chain rule), and this can be written $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 4{\sqrt{g(x)}}$  where $g(x) = 6-4x$.

Comment: I'm affraid i don't understand this: f(g(x))=f′(g(x))⋅g′(x)

Comment: I really should not have chosen the hardest math i could choose... :)

Comment: @amWhy Who said that it is the general formula for chain rule here? Not me of course. I’ve indicated the derivative for $\sqrt{g(x)}$ which is obtained by chain rule.

Comment: @gimusi I did, I asked if it was a general formula :)

Comment: The thing I don't understand is the g ' (x) part, what are you doing in that part?

Comment: @gimusi, I said "this answer shows how it [the chain rule] applies to your particular problem" and meant only that it is not the "general rule"  I was asnwering Mark's first comment here.

Comment: Mark.  Say $g(x) = 6-4x$.  What is $g'(x)$?  Step by step, $g'(x) = 0+-4 = -4$.

Comment: oh wow that was really simple

Comment: @MarcFijn it is a general formula for the square root obtained from the more general chain rule formula. Do you know what is the derivative of $\sqrt x$?

Comment: And I forgot the negative sign in my result above, which should be $$\frac 12\cdot -\frac 4{\sqrt{6-4x}} = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6-4x}}$$

Comment: The derivative of squareroot x is x^-1/2 right?

Comment: Almost Mark: The derivative of $\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$ is $\frac 12 \cdot x^{-1/2} = \frac 12\cdot \frac 1{x^{1/2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$

Comment: @MarkFijn Let use $(x^n)’=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: @amWhy I think I'm starting to understand now